# PHPMyadmin Export Database Very Slow

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

Ive just installed MariaDB 10.3.9 with PHPMyadmin 4.8.3 and PHP 7.1.22 on Centos 7. Now when I try to export a database using PHPMyadmin, it takes forever. Ive noticed that CPU usage is high during the process. On MariaDB, listing the processes, I see on my user a process running with status "checking permissions". If I kill that process, the export is completed right away, but opening the SQL file, I can see that just part of the export was completed. Testing this on another environment, I noticed that as I increase the number of databases on the server, more it takes to complete the export. It seems something related to the information_schema table. Any suggestions?

Database INFO:

Database size: 2.8MB
Number of records: 32698 (from all tables)
Number of tables: 212
Engine: MyISAM
Number of users on the server: 4164
Number of databases on the server: 4164

All databases have same structure and about the same size.

Thanks!
Andre Fagundes

Comment: You didnt give any important info here. Database size, number of records you export, table structure etc..

Comment: Database size: 2.8MB
Number of records: 32698 (from all tables)
Number of tables: 212
Engine: MyISAM

Comment: Can you try exporting with `mysqldump` and see if it's the same or faster?

Comment: Also, the problem could be because of many databases/users which slows down information_schema a lot. Try `set global innodb_stats_on_metadata=0;` and then export from phpmyadmin to see if it changes.

Comment: innodb_stats_on_metadata is already set to 0. I believe thats the default for Mariadb 10. mysqldump is very fast.

Comment: Strange. Phpmyadmin is supposed to use mysqldump behind the scenes (for sql export). Maybe it's executing some unoptimized information_schema queries before mysqldump. Do you see any query stuck on system tables during export ?

Comment: SELECT*,
`TABLE_SCHEMA`AS`Db`,
`TABLE_NAME`AS`Name`,
`TABLE_TYPE`AS`TABLE_TYPE`,
`ENGINE`AS`Engine`,
`ENGINE`AS`Type`,
`VERSION`AS`Version`,
`ROW_FORMAT`AS`Row_format`,
`TABLE_ROWS`AS`Rows`,
`AVG_ROW_LENGTH`AS`Avg_row_length`,
`DATA_LENGTH`AS`Data_length`,
`MAX_DATA_LENGTH`AS`Max_data_length`,

Comment: continuation ...

`INDEX_LENGTH`AS`Index_length`,
`DATA_FREE`AS`Data_free`,
`AUTO_INCREMENT`AS`Auto_increment`,
`CREATE_TIME`AS`Create_time`,
`UPDATE_TIME`AS`Update_time`,
`CHECK_TIME`AS`Check_time`,
`TABLE_COLLATION`AS`Collation`,
`CHECKSUM`AS`Checksum`,
`CREATE_OPTIONS`AS`Create_options`,
`TABLE_COMMENT`AS`Comment`
FROM`information_schema`.`TABLES`t
WHERE`TABLE_SCHEMA`COLLATEutf8_bin
IN('c12527_loja')
ANDt.`TABLE_NAME`COLLATEutf8_bin='marketplace_b2w_pedidos'ORDERBYNameASC

Comment: SELECT TRIGGER_SCHEMA, TRIGGER_NAME, EVENT_MANIPULATION, EVENT_OBJECT_TABLE, ACTION_TIMING, ACTION_STATEMENT, EVENT_OBJECT_SCHEMA, EVENT_OBJECT_TABLE, DEFINER FROM information_schema.TRIGGERS WHERE EVENT_OBJECT_SCHEMA COLLATE utf8_bin= 'c12527_loja' AND EVENT_OBJECT_TABLE COLLATE utf8_bin = 'pagamento_komercis'

Comment: The queries above takes around 2 seconds to complete

Answer (score 0):

Setting $cfg['Servers'][$i]['DisableIS'] to true on PHPMyadmin fixed the issue. Is there any downside setting that to true?

Comment: From the manual:  "Enabling this option might give you a big performance boost on older MySQL servers."  Since MariaDB 10.3.9 is very new, I suspect "false" is intended for MySQL 8.0.  Sounds safe.